# How to set Thunderbird as default mail client?

Tags: email, thunderbird, default-programs

On **Ubuntu 22.04LTS** I tested a different mail client that set itself as default, now uninstalled.

Since I mainly use **Thunderbird 91.9.1** as mail client, I want to set it back as default. However, for some reason I can't choose it under default applications, it is greyed out. Strangely enough, under I may choose it as default Calendar.

[image]

I also tried

```
sudo update-alternatives --all
```

but couldn't find options for mail or email.

I believe I compiled Thunderbird manually a while ago, since I wanted the newest version. It can be found under `/etc/thunderbird`. I have a .desktop file under

```
./.local/share/applications/thunderbird91.desktop
```

that looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Thunderbird 91.0
Comment=Send and receive mail with Thunderbird
Keywords=Email;E-mail;Newsgroup;Feed;RSS
Exec=/home/jay/thunderbird/thunderbird %U
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Type=Application
Icon=/home/jay/thunderbird/chrome/icons/default/default128.png
Categories=Application;Network;Email;
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/mailto;application/x-xpinstall;
StartupNotify=true
Actions=Compose;Contacts

[Desktop Action Compose]
Name=Compose New Message
Exec=/home/jay/thunderbird/thunderbird -compose
OnlyShowIn=Messaging Menu;Unity;
```

I simply click on the sidebar as usual to launch Thunderbird.

Any ideas?

Comment: I just checked my settings: I have "Thunderbird" as default mail client, but I can choose "Evolution" or "Mozilla Thunderbird email/news" from the dropdown list. So something is wrong here. I use the standard distro version `1:91.9.1+build1-0ubuntu0.22.04.1`.

Comment: You compiled the program yourself? Then perhaps you did not properly install a desktop launcher.

Comment: my instance of TB on 22.04 LTS is the current version 91.10.0.

Comment: When you want to use Thunderbird, how do you launch it?

Comment: @MDeBusk I have a .desktop file and simply click on the sidebar, please see update.

Comment: @vanadium I think so yes, a year ago when in 19.04 the new version was not available in repos. I've updated the question with the .desktop file I use.

Comment: You say the program can be found at /etc/thunderbird but your .desktop file says it's at /home/jay/thunderbird/thunderbird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the configuration file `~/.config/mimeapps.list` and add/edit `x-scheme-handler/mailto` to point to the `.desktop` file of your email program, e.g.

```
x-scheme-handler/mailto=thunderbird91.desktop;
```

For this to work, the `.desktop` file must reside in a directory searched by the menu system, e.g. `~/.local/share/applications/thunderbird91.desktop`